# Using BSS84 P-channel MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am using a P-channel MOSFET as a switch in my design & I have connected the drain to the load. The load needs 0.8mA of current. How can I decide whether the MOSFET is conducting that much current if I connect the source of the MOSFET to 3V ? The MOSFET used is BSS84 from Fairchild & the link for BSS84 datasheet is given below.

[BSS84 P-channel MOSFET](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/BS/BSS84.pdf)

Comment: More info needed. LOad is what> resistor ? what value ? If you connect load from 3V to ground what curr ent does it draw? have you got  atest meter ?

Comment: Madhu, are you sure that you have to drive 0.8 mA? It's a pretty small current, can I ask you what are you driving?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the graph of your datasheet that gives all the information you need:

[image: I_D vs. V_GS]

So assuming this circuit

[image]

V_GS is -3V which allows I_D to be up to ca. 0.5 A.

**EDIT:**
clabacchio is right pointing out that the graph is actually for V_DS = 5V.
Of  course a graph for V_DS = 3V would be better, but there isn't one in the datasheet.
So the question is: Will the resistance R_DSON be different for very low drain currents?
Looking at Figure 2 ("On-Resistance Variation with Drain Current and Gate Voltage") gives the answer:
it does change vs. I_DS, but only for currents above ca. 0.1 A and: resistance even gets lower (=better) for lower I_DS.

Comment: The current spec is 0.8 mA (may be wrong?) and the VDS for that graph is 5V, too high for this application

Comment: I think Curd is write with that 2 figures. From the graph, Id for 3V Vgs is approximately 0.5A to 0.6A. But I need only 0.8mA for programming an EEPROM (i.e, Programming Current). Now, I want to know how much current that EEPROM will take?

Comment: @clabacchio: concerning I_D: The OP wants to use the MOSFET as switch (not as current source). 
Since 0.5 A >> 0.8mA this is ok. Concerning V_DS: see my EDIT

Comment: @Madhu ok, my assumption about current sources was wrong, I read a different thing :)

Comment: Anyway I think it would be better posting Fig 1 and saying that at the specified current level the VDS is very small (close to 0).